# How to link an FX property of multiple layers?

Tags: after-effects

I'm evaluating an after effects plugin , which has an FX property `brightness` and similar. I have several layers on top of each other, each letting a portion of the others shine through.

Now I want to animate these FX properties on each layer. Is it possible to create some kind of "master" keyframe control that then triggers the same FX property on all layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so.  Add a Slider (in the Effects window) to one of your tracks, then use the pickwhip to parent the value of the slider to each of the other Brightness controls.

Examples here of using Sliders and pick whips:
http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-basics.html

Comment: What if my "brightness" control parameter does not show a pickwhip icon, and is furthermore inside a composition, and the slider should not be inside that comp? Also, the slider properties of the slider FX does not have a pickwhip either.

Comment: OK probably I have to use expressions here and connect the slider with the control by this expression. That works. If there is a "simpler" way please comment, otherwise I'll accept thhis.

Comment: The brightness control doesn't have to show a pick whip icon. You only have to drag the pick whip from the slider to the brightness control value (the number itself). If it's in another comp this is still doable- you can open multiple timelines at the same time in AE, and drag from one to the other.